# Image not being received from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

All the other information being stored within the database is on the website just not the image which is a BLOB image. Database holds the image as if you press it will show the image being stored. Any appreciated!

GetImage.php

```
<?php
include "connection.php";

$ID = $_GET["ID"];

$SQLCommand = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID = '$ID'";
$Result = mysqli_query($con, $SQLCommand);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result);

header("Content-type:" . $row["Name"]);
echo $row["Image"];

?>
```

shop.php

```
<?php
include "connection.php";

$SQLCommand = "SELECT * FROM products";
$Result = mysqli_query($con, $SQLCommand);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result)){
echo "<p id='p1'>" . $row["Name"] .
     "<br></p><p id='p3'>£" . $row["Price"] .
              "<br><br><img src=GetImage.php?ID=" . $row["ID"] . "         width=10%>" .
         "<br><a href=productdetails.php?ID=" . $row["ID"] . ">Details</a></p>".
         "<p id='p2'><a href=BasketAdd.php?ID=" . $row["ID"] . ">Add to     Basket</a><br><br>";
}
?>
```

InsertImageform

```
    <html>
<body>
<form action="UploadFile.php" method="post"
```

enctype="multipart/form-data">

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><p>
Description: <input type="text" name="description" id="description"><p>
Price: <input type="text" name="price" id="price"><p>
Protein: <input type="text" name="protein" id="protein"><p>
Type: <input type="text" name="type" id="type"><p>

Filename: <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you could use,

```
<?php
    include "connection.php";

    $SQLCommand = "SELECT * FROM products";
    $Result = mysqli_query($con, $SQLCommand);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result)){
    echo "<p id='p1'>" . $row["Name"] .
         "<br></p><p id='p3'>£" . $row["Price"] .
                  "<br><br><img src=" . base64_encode($row['image']) . "         width=10%>" .
             "<br><a href=productdetails.php?ID=" . $row["ID"] . ">Details</a></p>".
             "<p id='p2'><a href=BasketAdd.php?ID=" . $row["ID"] . ">Add to     Basket</a><br><br>";
    }
?>
```

You should use the `base64_encode()` function to read the BLOB image.

Comment: Hi @thewebmstr unfortunately that hasn't worked thanks for trying to help

Comment: Additionally, you should create a column that stores only a binary type for images and that base64_encode() can encode the binary format into image format.

Comment: Your format is incorrect.   It should be `src="data:image/jpg;" . base64,base64_encode($row['image']) . '"/>`. Then what about gif and png?  But that okay because the problem is more likely when the image was saved into the table.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with images in a database are generally related to how the image was stored in the database.

The image can be stored as a binary, but it is less problematic if stored as base64.

What I would need to see is the code that stores the image in the database. 
Given a file input with a name of "image"

```
<input type="file" name="image">
```

Then

```
if( is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) || !($_FILES['image']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)){
   $img = base64_encode($_FILES['image']);
   $sql = "INSERT INTO `images`(`image`) VALUES('$img')";
   ...
 }
```

Or as an update:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `image`='$img' WHERE ...
```

In the table the field image would have a type of "TEXT"

**BUT THAT IS STILL NOT ENOUGH...**

You need to know the dimensions and the type of image.

```
if( is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']) || !($_FILES['image1']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)){
  $save = false;
  switch(strtolower($_FILES['image1']['type'])){
  case 'image/jpeg':
    $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
  case 'image/png':
    $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
  case 'image/gif':
    $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
  default:
    $img = @getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    switch(strtolower($img['mime'])){
    case 'image/jpeg':
      $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
      $type = 'jpg';
      if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
    case 'image/png':
      $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
      $type = 'png';
      if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
    case 'image/gif':
      $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
      $type = 'gif';
      if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
    default:
      $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $ext = substr($filename,-3);
      switch(strtolower($ext)){
      case 'jpg':
        $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      case 'gif':
        $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      case 'png':
        $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      default:
        $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
        $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
        $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Get width and height

```
$width  = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);
$base64 = base64_encode($image);
```

Put it all together for an HTML `<img>`

```
$img = "<img  width=\"$width \" height=\"$height\" src=\"data:image/$type;base64,$base64\" alt =\"image\"/>";
```

Comment: I have added the insert image form to the first post I did

Comment: I was referring to the SQL to INSERT or UPDATE the table.  It's not as easy as it appears. What if someone uploads a file that is not an image?  What about the type?  You don;t want to put restrictions on the users because you don't know how to deal with multiple image types do you?  You cannot beat this routine.  The file extension can be wrong, the HTTP mime type can be wrong, but if it's a jpg, gif, or png, this routine gets it right.  And if not `$save` will be false.  You need to know the type so when you use the base64 you have what is need to fill in the `data:image/$type;base64,`